# StoryBoardを利用せずにPresentModallySegueを利用する方法

Tags: swift

カスタムView（xib)を表示する際に、PresentModallySegueのように表示したいのです。

そのためにはStoryboardを利用せずにコードだけでSegueのモノマネをしなければなりません。

この方法は可能でしょうか？

可能であればどのように実装するかご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前提として、Viewではなく、ViewControllerの表示として回答しますが、

**可能**です。

UIViewControllerの[present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)メソッドを使用してください。

なお、Storyboardが導入された iOS ５ 以前にはSegueもありませんでしたので、常にそのようにモーダルなビューコントローラーは表示されていました。
（実際には前身の[presentModalViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621465-presentmodalviewcontroller)が使われていました）

**追記**

文字通り

> カスタムView（xib)を表示する

場合でも、ViewをViewControllerに紐付けて、ViewControllerとして表示する必要があります。

そのためには、UIViewController（またはそのサブクラス)を [init(nibName:bundle:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init)で初期化します。

例

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // (略)

    func someButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // nib(xib)を使ってViewControllerのインスタンスを作成する
        let modalVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "xibのファイル名", bundle: nil)
        // 作成したViewControllerをモーダル表示する
        self.present(modalVC, animated: true) {
            print("モーダル表示完了")
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    // (略)
}
```

ViewControllerをxibのOwnerに指定することで、Viewの上に載せたボタンやラベルとViewControllerのIBOutletやIBActionを紐付ける事ができます。
これもどちらかというとStoryBoard登場以前によく使われた方法になります。

Comment: 返信が遅れて申し訳ありません。
例までご丁寧にありがとうございます。
まさに、Xibで利用しようとしていたのでとても参考になります！